# Vertically align horizontal inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I've got a checkbox group. Which are centrally aligned with checkboxes on top and text below. Here is what I mean :

[image]

So I want to align

So each checkbox + label is wrapped in a div with class `choice`. All `choice` divs are part of div with `additional-info`. `choice` divs are inline-block elements with fixed width.

How do I align `div` choice to be in the same height as the first one?

I've tried setting the `additional-info` position to relative and `choice` to absolute. But then they overlap each other so that wasn't good.

Also tried setting the `choice` div display to inline but then the current layout breaks and divs are displayed in the middle in three rows.

Also tried to set `additional-info` display to table-cell and adding vertical-align top but that didn't work either.

What else can I try? any suggestions is welcome

**Update :**

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="additional-info">
  <p class="text required control-label">
    Additional info
  </p>
  <div class="input boolean optional certificate"><input name="user[certificate]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="certificate"><input class="boolean optional require-one" id="certificate" name="user[certificate]" type="checkbox" value="1">I've got a valid certificate and permits</label></div>
  <div class="input boolean optional no_garden"><input name="user[no_garden]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="no_garden"><input class="boolean optional require-one" id="no_garden" name="user[no_garden]" type="checkbox" value="1">I don't have garden</label></div>
  <div class="input boolean optional has_garden"><input name="user[has_garden]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="has_garden"><input class="boolean optional require-one" id="has_garden" name="user[has_garden]" type="checkbox" value="1">I have a garden</label></div>
</div>
```

Some css :

```
.additional-info {
  position: relative;
}

.additional-info div {
  width: 32.6%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Mr. Alien alright coming right up. thanks

Comment: do it in a list easier to code and easier to use. People generally read from left to right so a list is easier to scan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look here, I've made it from scratch...

So what I did here is, I've used `display: table;` for the container element and am using `display: table-cell;` for the child `div` and as the child `div` are now table cells, I used `vertical-align: top;` so that the elements align to the `top` in those cells

```css
section {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

section > div {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h4>Additional Info</h4>
<section>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><br />
    <label for="">I've got a valid certificate permits</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><br />
    <label for="">I've got a valid certificate</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" /><br />
    <label for="">I certificate</label>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: ok I was setting table-cell to the parent div (additional-info), now I get the point. This works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a simple float to get rid of the remaining 'white space':

```
.additional-info div {
  width: 32.6%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```css
.additional-info {
  position: relative;
}

.additional-info div {
  width: 32.6%;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="additional-info">
    <p class="text required control-label">Additional info</p>
    <div class="input boolean optional certificate">
        <input name="user[certificate]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="certificate">
            <input class="boolean optional require-one" id="certificate" name="user[certificate]" type="checkbox" value="1">I've got a valid certificate and permits</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input boolean optional no_garden">
        <input name="user[no_garden]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="no_garden">
            <input class="boolean optional require-one" id="no_garden" name="user[no_garden]" type="checkbox" value="1">I don't have garden</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input boolean optional has_garden">
        <input name="user[has_garden]" type="hidden" value="0">
        <label class="boolean optional control-label checkbox" for="has_garden">
            <input class="boolean optional require-one" id="has_garden" name="user[has_garden]" type="checkbox" value="1">I have a garden</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done an inline-block level based on what you said above. Using a set width on the parent div and then child elements forces the items to stack rather than appear in a horizontal list.

```
<div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;">
<div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;"><input /></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;"><input /></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;"><input /></div>
    <div style="display:inline-block; width:150px;"><input /></div>
</div>
```

Worth trying to see if it works for your form?

(I know I've done it here as inline-style, but this is just as an example I quickly put together)