# How to align text vertically centered together with inline-block elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following code:

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/e63Y4/1/)

---

**HTML**

```
<a href="#">
    text
    <ins></ins>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    //vertical-align: middle; (does not change anything...)
}
ins {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
}
```

---

Now, it looks like this:

[image]

---

But it should look like this:

[image]

---

**How can I achieve this desired vertical alignment of the text?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20947224/vertically-align-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add vertical-align: middle; to ins:

```
ins {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[<kbd>**JS Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/e63Y4/2/)

Comment: Ahh, I think I finally begin to understand how this attribute works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Get your text in a `<span>` and style like that

```
<a href="#">
    <span>text</span>
    <ins></ins>
</a>

span{
    float:left;
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:5px;
}

a {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;

}
ins {
    display:inline-block;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background:blue;
}
```